# Rendering a large amount of text within a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, calayer, catiledlayer

I have a `UIView` in a `UIScrollView`. The `UIScrollView` only scrolls vertically, and doesn't zoom.

In the `UIView's` `drawRect:` method I'm trying to color the background and draw some text. When the text's relatively short both operations work fine. When the text's longer however, the `UIView` becomes so large that both operations silently fail. With long text the `CGContext` is around 640x17278 device pixels, which I guess is too big for the GPU/whatever to handle.

What's the best way to go about breaking the `CALayer` into multiple contexts to render into?

I've actually dealt with a very similar problem before and i went with `CATiledLayer`, but I remember it being a pain to work with and there being a noticeable delay between a tile appearing and it being rendered. Are there any other ways I could go about doing it?

The text is already laid out at this stage, it's just a matter of calling `CGContextSetTextPosition` and `CTLineDraw` for each line.